# Use CakePHP $this inside PHP function

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
function search_reset ()
{
    $search_query = $_GET['q'];

    if($search_query)
    {
        echo $this->Html->link('Clear', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'), array('title' => 'Clear search query'));
    }   
}
```

But it causes the following error: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /Users/cameron/Sites/smplr/app/views/search/index.ctp on line 9`

I have two questions:

1.) What do I use INSTEAD of `$this` when inside a function?
2.) Where would I put a custom function like this? As I can't put it inside my controller as it's NOT an action.

Comment: is search_reset() in a class?

Comment: it's currently sat at the top of my view as I don't where to put it as I can't put it in the controller without it becoming an action which I don't want it to be.

Comment: `$this` is only available in methods of objects. This is PHP related and not specific to CakePHP.

Comment: If you want to use `this` on that particular function and want to keep the function isolated (not make it a method of the class) you should pass the object to the function: `function search_reset($this)`

Comment: @Frankie I'm looking to make these functions accessible SITE-WIDE any ideas on how I could this? Thanks

Comment: @Cameron, there should be a disclaimer here that I've never used Cake before. Nevertheless this should work: Have this function in a file and include that file where needed. The function will be feed an object and manipulate it as needed. `function example($object)` and you can then use `object` and its methods. Remember that $this is only a pointer to the current object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Cameron, Here is how you make this available site wide. First, create your custom helper and put it in the views/helpers/ directory as search_reset.php

```
<?php
class SearchResetHelper extends AppHelper {

  var $helpers = array('Html');  // include the HTML helper

  /**
  * @param string $query, This is the search query you will pass from the view
  */
  function reset_link($query = null) {
     if($query == null) {
        return;
     }    

    if(!empty($query)) {
        return $this->Html->link('Clear', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),  array('title' => 'Clear search query'));
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in your controller, make sure you include this in the $helpers array at the top:

```
var $helpers = array('SearchReset','any','other','helpers');
```

Now in your view, you simple call:

```
<?php echo $this->SearchReset->reset_link($_GET['q']); ?>
```

Then you will get the link as needed. It will work in any view as long as you call the helper in the controller.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Awesome! So I presume what would normally be a function in a normal PHP website becomes a Helper when working with MVC?

Comment: Correct. You could have added the function to every view, but then it defeats the purpose of the architecture. This makes it reusable across ALL views. The other options was to do as @deceze suggested and put it in the app_helper. I prefer to be selective about what I put in my app_helper. When I create helpers, I like to make them portable to other apps without having to use the entire app_helper.

Comment: In your view, call <?php echo $this->SearchReset->reset_link($_GET['q']); ?>

Comment: @mac, you are correct. Now with the CakePHP 2.x, `$this` is required. Back when this was written, `$SearchReset` was acceptable in CakePHP 1.x.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm looking to make these functions accessible SITE-WIDE any ideas on how I could this?

[Create your own Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1097/Creating-Helpers) or add it as a [method in the AppHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1101/Creating-Functionality-for-All-Helpers).

Comment: Say I add those functions into my app_helper how do I access them? As just calling the functions doesn't work?

Comment: @Cameron The AppHelper is the base class that all Helpers inherit from. I.e. any method you add to the AppHelper class, any Helper will have. I.e. you can call `$this->Html->search_reset()`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's in your ctp, you have access to it directly (without $this). You should just be able to write a function in your template and include as a global:

```
function search_reset ()
{
    global $html;
    $search_query = $_GET['q'];

    if($search_query)
    {
        echo $html->link('Clear', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'), array('title' => 'Clear search query'));
    }   
}
```

To include html helper in your app controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {    
    public function constructClasses(){
        //Apply App helpers and merge with controller helpers 
        $helpers = array('Html','Javascript' /*add whatever you want, these are global*/);
        //merge global, controller helpers
            $this->helpers = array_merge($this->helpers, $helpers); 
        parent::constructClasses(); 
    }
}
```

The above code will merge the helpers specified there with any other helpers specified in your controller. Then you can use $html helper in any ctp file.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ causes this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/smplr/app/views/search/index.ctp on line 10` BUT should I even be putting a function like this inside a view?

Comment: I do it. I don't see a prob with a local function for a view. Are you sure you have that helper included properly? Does $html->link() work outside of the function?

Comment: Well `$html->link` is pre 1.3 cake and I have included the helper but still get the error. But what about moving the function somewhere else so it's accessible SITE-WIDE? Where would it go?

Comment: $html->link() comes from the Html helper. If you don't have it in your version and can't upgrade, I suggest making your own helper that does what you want and including it in your controllers. You can also make an app_controller (in your app root) where you can include helpers for all controllers if you want it to be site-wide.

Comment: I put those functions inside app_controller but they don't work? Care to show an example of how to allow them inside the file? Also the Helper isn't written like `$html->` it's now `$this->Html` in 1.3 the other doesn't work anymore!

Comment: I am using 1.3 current, and $html->link does work, that is what you use inside a .ctp. Updating my example...

Comment: To include a Helper in all controllers, just add it to the `AppController::$helper` property, like any other helper in any other controller. No need at all to override `constructClasses`.